# how to copy-paste through mouse in react select

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any way to implement copy-paste using mouse in react select. It is possible using ctr + v but not work as expected when right click on select input field

Comment: What do you mean by using mouse ? Doing Right click + paste ? Or just clicking on mousewheel for example? We need more details.

Comment: I mean right click on select input field and paste the copied text

Comment: I think you forgot learning JavaScript, specially  DOM and clipboard API

Comment: Here they are https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API

Comment: You should probably take a look at `ClipboardEvent`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData . I've done something similar but it's on Angular.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using AsyncSelect, you can do it like so by using styles prop

```
styles={{
  placeholder: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    pointerEvents: "none",
    userSelect: "none",
    MozUserSelect: "none",
    WebkitUserSelect: "none",
    msUserSelect: "none"
  }),
  input: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    input: {
      gridArea: '1 / 2 / 4 / 4 !important'
    }
  }),
}}
```

We basically make the nested input element take full width. Now, we can right click on it and see the paste option.